# How can you extract associated values from a specific instance of an enum's case?

Tags: swift, enums, associated-object

Consider this enum...

```
enum SelectionMode {
    case none     (position:TextPosition)
    case normal   (startPosition:TextPosition, endPosition:TextPosition)
    case lines    (startLineIndex:Int, endLineIndex:Int)
}
```

If it's passed into a function, you can use a switch statement with each case receiving the associated values, like so...

```
let selectionMode:SelectionMode = .lines(4, 6)

switch sectionMode {
    case let .none   (position): break;
    case let .normal (startPosition, endPosition): break;
    case let .lines  (startLineIndex, endLineIndex):
        // Do something with the indexes here

}
```

What I'm wondering is if I know for instance I'm being handed a '.lines' version, how can I get the associated values without having to use a switch statement?

i.e. can I do something like this?

```
let selectionMode:SelectionMode = .lines(4, 6)

let startLineIndex = selectionMode.startLineIndex
```

So is something similar to this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple assignment without any runtime check won't work because the
compiler cannot know which value the `selectionMode` variable contains.
If your program logic guarantees that it is `.lines` then
you can extract the associated value with pattern matching:

```
guard case .lines(let startLineIndex, _) = selectionMode else {
    fatalError("Expected a .lines value")
    // Or whatever is appropriate ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: AMAZING! This even works for if statement. `if case .lines(let startLineIndex, _) = selectionMode { // do stuff }`